# insert datetime value gives error "Incorrect syntax near 12"

Tags: c#, sql

```
DateTime myDateTime =  Convert.ToDateTime(rd2[0].ToString())
values = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + " , " + rd2[1].ToString()+ " , " + rd2[2].ToString()+ " , " + rd2[3].ToString()+ " , " + rd2[4].ToString()+ " , " + rd2[5].ToString() ;
```

i am trying to insert date 2016-04-22 12:58:11 in sql server table of datatype datetime but it gives error "Incorrect syntax near 12"

Comment: is this the error in server or db

Comment: use parameterised query

Comment: I believe you need some form of quote around the myDateTime.ToString() in the values string.

Comment: i am doing it in c# trying to insert in sql

Comment: If you share your SQL, you'll start getting messages about how susceptible to SQL injection your code is. Don't treat SQL like a bunch of strings that you need to glue together. As has been already said, use parameterized queries.

Comment: no need of quote as i am storing in string

Comment: @sacpat yes, you do need a quote mark if you intend to simply concatenate your SQL like that. Instead, as others have said, use a parameterized query. It is far more readable, maintainable and secure then that mess you have created.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The string you end up with is similar to this:

```
2016-04-22 00:00:00,2016-04-22 00:00:00,2016-04-22 00:00:00,2016-04-22 00:00:00
```

Inserting that into a SQL statement is invalid. You need to wrap each date in single quotes so that you have:

```
'2016-04-22 00:00:00','2016-04-22 00:00:00','2016-04-22 00:00:00','2016-04-22 00:00:00'
```

Either way this makes your life difficult and makes your code subject to sql injection and insecure. Consider using parameters like this.

```
string exampleSQL = "SELECT * from mydatetable where dateOne = @date1 and dateTwo = @date2";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(/* connection info */);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

command.Parameters.Add("@date1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = myDateTime;
command.Parameters.Add("@date2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = rd2[1];
```

This way you dont need to worry about formatting. The system automatically will replace the @date1 and @date2 with the values you specified and it will deal with adding the nescessary structure of the SQL without you having to worry about it.

Comment: Upvote from my side, but you really should read this [Can we stop using addwithvalue already](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Although I think it is pretty safe with `DateTime` it is [generally better to specify your parameter data type rather than use `AddWithValue`](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). `AddWithValue` must infer the parameter data type from the data being provided, which can lead to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Ah, i wasnt aware of that problem. Thanks. Ill update the code.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest using "parametrizing your sql queries"...For example, you can check it out here:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/268104-the-right-way-to-query-a-database-parameterizing-your-sql-queries/

Cheers!

Comment: I upvoted, then took it away. This is the right answer, but you need to add details rather than relying on 3rd party content.

Comment: if that site ever goes down, this answer becomes useless.

Comment: Hi, The next time i will do the copy&paste. ;-)